# Modify launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
python3 -m src.scripts.training --model sit --data_path ./dev --embeddings_location ./embeddings --default_save_path ./results/ --weights_save_path ./weights --train_batch_size 32 --test_batch_size 32 --n_jobs_for_mcts 1 --val_check_interval 1.0 --gpus 1 --distributed_backend=""
```

I would like to debug my program in using this command line. To do that, I know I have to modify the `launch.json` file in VS Code. Here is my attempt:

```
{
    "name": "State Ete 2021",
    "type": "python3",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args":["-m", "src.scripts.training", "--model sit", "--data_path", "./dev", "--embeddings_location", "./embeddings", "--default_save_path", "./results/", "--weights_save_path", "./weights", "--train_batch_size", "32", "--test_batch_size", "32", "--n_jobs_for_mcts", "1", "--val_check_interval", "1.0", "--gpus", "1", "--distributed_backend", "''"]
}
```

I am not sure how to finish configuring this part of the `launch.json`. It doesn't seem to work. How can I fix that?

**EDIT**

I use a Conda environment named `projet_ete`. Do I have to mention it in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

**args:**

Specifies arguments to pass to the Python program. **Each element of the argument string that's separated by a space should be contained within quotes**, for example:

```
"args": ["--quiet", "--norepeat", "--port", "1593"],
```

From the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_args)

So, you need to change as follows:

`"--model sit"` to `"--model","sit"`,

`"--distributed_backend", "''"` to `"--distributed_backend=\"\""`